# How to select image from a p tag in jsoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have a p tag like this

```
<p><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-610" src="https://muslimmemo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/al-rundi-fall-seville-poem-arabic.png" alt="al-rundi-fall-seville-poem-arabic" width="591" height="606" /></p>
```

I can get the p tag by `Elements pTag = document.select("p");` 
I have two problems:

> 1. I want to get the image from the above p tag in jsoup.
> 2. How would I know whether a p tag has an image or not?

How can I achieve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the image tag with select("img") again. If you do so you could check, if the Elements are empty or not and if you want to get the src attribute then use img.attr("src").
Could look like that:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JSoupAnswer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String p = "<p><img class=\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-610\" src=\"https://muslimmemo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/al-rundi-fall-seville-poem-arabic.png\" alt=\"al-rundi-fall-seville-poem-arabic\" width=\"591\" height=\"606\" /></p>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(p);
        Elements img = doc.select("p").select("img");
        if (img.size() > 0)
            System.out.println(img);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-610" src="https://muslimmemo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/al-rundi-fall-seville-poem-arabic.png" ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used pTags.select("img").first() != null to solve the issue..